# When is ObjectQuery really an IOrderedQueryable?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, interface

Applied to entity framework, the extension methods `Select()` and `OrderBy()` both return an `ObjectQuery`, which is defined as:

```
public class ObjectQuery<T> : ObjectQuery, IOrderedQueryable<T>,
    IQueryable<T>, <... more interfaces>
```

The return type of `Select()` is `IQueryable<T>` and that of `OrderBy` is `IOrderedQueryable<T>`. So you could say that both return the same type but in a different wrapper. Luckily so, because now we can apply `ThenBy` after `OrderBy` was called.

Now my problem.

Let's say I have this:

```
var query = context.Plots.Where(p => p.TrialId == 21);
```

This gives me an `IQueryable<Plot>`, which is an `ObjectQuery<Plot>`. But it is also an IOrderedQueryable:

```
var b = query is IOrderedQueryable<Plot>; // True!
```

But still:

```
var query2 = query.ThenBy(p => p.Number); // Does not compile.
// 'IQueryable<Plot>' does not contain a definition for 'ThenBy'
// and no extension method 'ThenBy' ....
```

When I do:

```
var query2 = ((IOrderedQueryable<Plot>)query).ThenBy(p => p.Number);
```

It compiles, but gives a runtime exception:

> Expression of type '`` IQueryable`1[Plot] ``' cannot be used for parameter of type `` 'IOrderedQueryable`1[Plot] ``' of method '`` IOrderedQueryable`1[Plot] ThenBy[Plot,Nullable`1](IOrderedQueryable`1[Plot], Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Plot,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]]]) ``'

The cast is carried out (I checked), but the parameter of `ThenBy` is still seen as IQueryable (which puzzles me a bit).

Now suppose some method returns an `ObjectQuery<Plot>` to me as `IQueryable<Plot>` (like `Select()`). What if I want to know whether it is safe to call `ThenBy` on the returned object. How can I figure it out if the `ObjectQuery` is "real" or a "fake" `IOrderedQueryable` without catching exeptions?

Comment: I'd advise against checking the concrete type as it will tie you to your query provider which is exactly what `IQueryable` avoids.  One approach is a quick walk of the expression to check for the `SortBy()` method but I suspect somebody will point out something easier.  If not, comment on here and I'll provide you the code to walk the tree.  Good luck

Comment: @Smudge202 Thanks. There are a lot places much more fun to walk than expression trees, but if you can't resist... But yes, maybe someone else.

Comment: @Smudge202 btw, checking the concrete type wouldn't work anyway because it implements both interfaces. It puzzles me that ordinary reflection does not help here, so probably a deeper inspection as you suggest is the only way if I really need to know.

Comment: Yeh, I didn't think it possible by examining concrete types - perhaps a saving grace? =)  Good luck with the deeper inspection.  I suspect it may be possible through some form of reflection, but definitely possible as advised through expression trees.  Good luck on either approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expression Trees are genuinely good fun! (or perhaps I'm a little bit of a freak) and will likely become useful in many a developer's future if [Project Roslyn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2011/10/19/introducing-the-microsoft-roslyn-ctp.aspx) is anything to go by! =)

In your case, simple inherit from MSDN's [ExpressionVisitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882521%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), and override the `VisitMethodCall` method in an inheriting class with something to compare `m.MethodInfo` with `SortBy` (i.e. if you're not too fussy simply check the name, if you want to be fussy use reflection to grab the actual SortBy MethodInfo to compare with.

Let me know if/what you need examples of, but honestly, after copy/pasting the ExpressionVisitor you'll probably need no more than 10 lines of non-expression-tree code ;-)

Hope that helps

Comment: There, you did it. You infected me with the expression tree virus! It is a viable solution (btw the method name is "OrderBy") albeit specific to expressions and you're right, it's fun! So far for my walks in the park :). Although this worked here, I will also post a question that articulates the problem in pure C# terms.

Comment: For who is interested: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063131/how-to-tell-which-interface-is-returned-by-a-method) is the pure C# question.

Answer (score 1):

Although Expression Trees are good fun, wouldn't in this case the simple solution be to use OrderBy rather than ThenBy?

- `OrderBy` is an extension on `IQueryable` and returns an `IOrderedQueryable`.
- `ThenBy` is an extension on `IOrderedQueryable` and returns an `IOrderedQueryable`.

So if you have a IQueryable (as in your case above, where query is an IQueryable) and you want to apply an initial ordering to it, use `OrderBy`. `ThenBy` is only intended to apply additional ordering to an already ordered query.

If you have a LINQ result of some kind, but you aren't sure if it is an `IQueryable` or an `IOrderedQueryable` and want to apply additional filtering to it, you could make two methods like:

```
 static IOrderedQueryable<T, TKey> ApplyAdditionalOrdering<T, TKey>(this IOrderedQueryable<T, TKey> source, Expression<Func<T, TFilter>> orderBy)
        {
            return source.ThenBy(orderBy);
        }
```

And

```
static IOrderedQueryable<T, TKey> ApplyAdditionalOrdering<T, TKey>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, TFilter>> orderBy)
        {
            return source.OrderBy(orderBy);
        }
```

The compiler will figure out the correct one to call based on the compile-time type of your query object.

Comment: That's a smart solution. One drawback, it can't be used *inside* and expression. In the mean time I've never really had any need to know if an `IQueryable` had an initial sorting. It was only that I was puzzled by this no-op interface.