# How to tell which interface is returned by a method

Tags: c#, reflection, interface

Given this code snippet that can be readily pasted into Linqpad (or slightly modified in a Visual Studio console solution):

```
void Main()
{
    var cat = this.GetCat();
    var dog = this.GetDog();
    cat.Think();
    cat.ThinkHarder();
    //dog.Think(); // Does not compile.
    //dog.ThinkHarder(); // Does not compile.

    //if ([dog is returned as ISmartAnimal]) // What to put here?
        ((ISmartAnimal)dog).Think(); // Compiles, runs, but shouldn't.

    reportTypeProperties(cat);
    reportTypeProperties(dog);
}

interface IAnimal
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

interface ISmartAnimal : IAnimal
{
    void Think();
}

class Animal : IAnimal, ISmartAnimal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public void Think() { }
}

ISmartAnimal GetCat()
{
    return new Animal();
}

IAnimal GetDog()
{
    return new Animal();
}

static void reportTypeProperties(object obj)
{
    var type = obj.GetType();
    Console.WriteLine("Type: {0}", type.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("Is smart? {0}", obj is ISmartAnimal);
}

static class ext
{
    public static void ThinkHarder(this ISmartAnimal animal)
    { }
}
```

The output of `reportTypeProperties` shows that `dog`, although returned as IAnimal, "is" an ISmartAnimal. (Same for both objects)

> Type: Animal
>   Is smart? True

This is because `GetType()` returns the concrete type of the object, not its current interface.

My question. **Is there a way to tell that `dog` is returned as IAnimal?** (see pseudocode). The compiler knows (so does quickview). Suppose I had some animal object and I wanted to inspect in runtime code whether or not I can make it `Think()`.

Background:
This may seem an academic exercise. And it may seem strange to have a class (Animal) implement an interface (ISmartAnimal) that you don't want to expose always. But I ask because I encountered something similar in Entity Framework. If you want you can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025137/when-is-objectquery-really-an-iorderedqueryable), but it diverts to EF-specific features. If you don't want to delve into that it suffices to say that it's imperative that `Animal` implement both interfaces.

---

Disclaimer:
"Any resemblance to real animals is purely coincidental :)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're interested in the *compile-time type of the `dog` variable*. You can *sort* of get this, by making `ReportTypeProperties` generic and letting the compiler infer the type based on the variable's type:

```
static void ReportTypeProperties<T>(T obj)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Compile-time type: {0}", typeof(T).Name);
    Console.WriteLine("Actual type: {0}", obj.GetType().Name);
    Console.WriteLine("Is smart? {0}", obj is ISmartAnimal);
}
```

Note that this can be gamed in various ways, e.g.

```
object dog = GetDog();
ReportTypeProperties(dog); // Would show as object
```

or

```
IAnimal dog = GetDog();
ReportTypeProperties<object>(dog); // Would show as object
```

It's not really clear what the bigger picture is here - it feels unlikely to me that going in this direction is going to lead to a good design.

Comment: Thanks (again) Jon. It is not a design I would like to implement too often, but I was a bit surprised by EF's ObjectQuery (and DataQuery in linq-to-sql) doing the same with IQueryable and IOrderedQueryable. Although I'm sure there are good reasons to do it that way.