# Entity SQL Sort Then LINQ to Entities GroupBy Doesn't Return IOrderedQueryable

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, query-builder, entity-sql

**Works:** My UI sends up [entity sql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399560.aspx) sort expressions from a jqGrid to my DAL and then applies some Where clauses that get returned to my service layer. My service layer will then create a PaginatedList object that applies the Skip()..Take() to the IQueryable.
Example:

```
var qry = ((IObjectContextAdapter)DbContext).ObjectContext
.CreateQuery<TEntity>(entityName)
.OrderBy(pEntitySQLSort.GetEntitySQL()); 
//GetEntitySQL() i.e. "it.WorksheetID ASC"
return qry.Where(p=> pStatus == "blah").Skip(5).Take(10);
```

**Doesn't Work:** Applying a GroupBy() then Select() that returns a list of the same type of entities (Worksheet).
Example:

```
var qry = ((IObjectContextAdapter)DbContext).ObjectContext
.CreateQuery<TEntity>(entityName)
.OrderBy(pEntitySQLSort.GetEntitySQL());

var qryGrouped = qry.GroupBy(pWorksheet => pWorksheet.ParticipantID)
.Select(pGroup => new {Group = pGroup, LatestWorksheetID = pGroup.Max(pWorksheet => pWorksheet.WorksheetID)})
.Select(p => p.Group.FirstOrDefault(pWorksheet => pWorksheet.WorksheetID == p.LatestWorksheetID)); 

return qryGrouped.Skip(5).Take(10); //throws exception.
```

**Throws NotSupportedException: The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.**

It seems to me that the first snippet does return an IOrderedQueryable that applies the esql sorting expression but the second snippet does not? Or maybe does GroupBy() remove the ordering of a query/collection ? If this is is the case, and since esql must be applied BEFORE LINQ to Entities, how could I accomplish the sql sorting + LINQ GroupBy ?

Related:
[When is ObjectQuery really an IOrderedQueryable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025137/when-is-objectquery-really-an-iorderedqueryable)
[Why can't we mix ESQL and LINQ TO Entities](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/619db347-bd5c-4786-85ef-8b9baee41af2/#3fbc1d6a-ff48-4337-88c3-f9627d259051)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GroupBy()` returns an `IGrouping<int, Worksheet>`. The actual object is an `ObjectQuery` returned as `IQueryable`. You linked to my question (When is ObjectQuery really an IOrderedQueryable?), so you know that the fact that this `ObjectQuery` also implements `IOrderedQueryable` does not necessarily mean that it actually behaves as such.

In a [more elementary, related, question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063131/how-to-tell-which-interface-is-returned-by-a-method), Jon Skeet made the distinction between actual type and compile-time type. The compile-time type (`IQueryable`) is what matters.

So, `GroupBy` effectively cancels the previous `OrderBy`. In a quick test on a similar case I could see that even the ordering is gone in the grouping. Conclusion: you'll have to re-apply an `OrderBy` for the `Skip` to be executed successfully.

Comment: thanks! but that means it can't be done using esql since it MUST happen before any linq to entities according to Diego Vega .. correct?

Comment: I think you should be able to do `qryGrouped.OrderBy()` in your example.

Comment: Yes, i'm able to do OrderBy() linq entities but not with entity query builder. Query builder's method would be .OrderBy("it.WorksheetID DESC") but it's only available from ObjectQuery and once it's become IQueryable with linq2entities, you cant cast back to ObjectQuery to use this method. I don't want to accept that my only alternative is to write the entire query in entity sql including the group by clause... but i think that's the bottom line.. :-\

Comment: I'm afraid, yes. But you can use Limit and Skip, can't you? After OrderBy (esql), that is.

Comment: I thought I could at first, but then I thought, it doesn't make much sense to apply paging BEFORE the group by..then i'd be limiting the result set that gets grouped and this would return incomplete result..